# For loop to Create Lists - Python

Tags: python

I have one list that contains coordinates two elements that have a pair of coordinates each.

```py
cords = ["lat1,long1;lat2,long2","lat3,long3;lat4,long4"]
```

I need to break each set of coordinates out of "cord" and turn it into its own list using a for loop to automate the creation of the new lists. The number of coordinate pairs can change so i need a for loop that can create new lists for x number of coordinate pairs in the original list.

Needed outcome:

```py
cords1 =["lat1,long1 ; lat2,long2"]
cords2 =["lat3,long3 ; lat4,long4"]
```

Comment: Don't do this.  A list is already the perfect way to have a variable number of elements.  Do `cords = [[c] for c in cords]` if you want to just put each `c` in its own sublist.

Comment: What do you need a loop for when you can write: `cords1 = [cords[0]]; cords2 = [cords[1]]`?